# HTML5's contenteditable and oninput with Apache Wicket

Tags: html, wicket, wicket-1.6

I need editable text in an Apache Wicket Application. As the text has to appear very "common-table-like", with editing only after the user double clicks on the text and so on, using normal TextFields is not really an option.

So I decided to go for the new HTML5 attribute `contenteditable`, which does the overall job quite fine. With the following markup and Java code I get a label that looks like static text, but after the user clicks inside the text is editable:

```
<div wicket:id="id" contenteditable></div>

...

item.add(new Label("id", "dummy content"));
```

But now I obviously need to catch some event when the user actually edits the text, as the new text should be stored back into the database. Online manuals suggest using `oninput` as it seems more reliable (e.g. with respect to timing issues) than `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` and so on.

Trying the event with regular HTML5 works fine:

```
<div wicket:id="id" contenteditable oninput='alert("oninput");'></div>
```

My question is now, how can I get the Wicket Label to support `oninput`? Overriding it and creating a custom label would be a perfectly fine solution (if I really have to), but for that I am too new to Wicket as to know where to start and how to create the correct markup and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a `div` is not a form element, it doesn't get submitted when you post a form. So you have two options:

- in `onInput` fill a hidden form element with the content and submit that using a form
- send the content to the server using Ajax

Both require you to do some magic using a (Ajax)Behavior.

You can use Wicket's [HiddenField](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/HiddenField.html) to create the hidden field, and in `onInput` perform the update of the HiddenField's value.

You can encapsulate this by creating your own `ContentEditableFormComponent` by using [FormComponentPanel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponentPanel.html) as a starting point.